# Get value from JSON nested object key

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, algorithm

I'm trying to write a function gets a key (**string**) and **returns values of it** if it exists in the JSON.

Received JSON:

```json
[
  {
    "some_key1": [
      {"key": "value1"},
      {"key": "value2"},
      {"key": "value3"}
    ]
  },
  {
    "some_key2": [
      {"key": "value4"},
      {"key": "value5"},
      {"key": "value6"}
    ]
  },
  {
    "default_val": [
      {"key": "value7"},
      {"key": "value8"},
      {"key": "value9"}
    ]
  }
]
```

The structure looks like this and the only thing that might vary is the number of inner objects.

Function that would **return** the **array**:

```js
interface InnerObject {
    key: string;
}

const getValues = (key = "default_val"): InnerObject[] => {
    /* working code */
}
```

Example expected output:

```
> getValues("some_key2");
[{"key": "value4"},{"key": "value5"},{"key": "value6"}]
> getValues();
[{"key": "value7"},{"key": "value8"},{"key": "value9"}]
```

Any elegant solutions?

Comment: A loop with an `if`.

Comment: @zerkms I don't think it's the best thing to do if you have a couple hundred objects and you have to filter them on every click.

Comment: I do much more complex object filterings on click with tens of thousands of nodes with no visible issues.  I don't think that performance is likely an option until you hit at least hundreds of thousands.

Comment: @Bart "I don't think it's the best thing to do" --- there is nothing absolute "the best" ever: the solution either fits your requirements, or not. Given you have nothing at all - any solution is significantly better than your current one. Nevertheless - if you have such an unoptimal structure - what else do you expect but iteration over it?

Comment: is your data structure always going to be exactly `[{'some key name':[ {<arbitrary object>}...]}..., {'default_val':[ {<arbitrary object>}...]}]`, and you want to return `default_val` iff no key is given, no matter where it is in the array?

Comment: Hey @Bart, would you mark the best answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That structure is not ideal for searching.  Why not convert it to a better structure first, and use that for the searching?

Something like this might do:

```js
const makeSearcher = (input, obj = Object .assign (...input)) => (key) =>
  obj [key] || obj .default_val

const input = [{some_key1: [{key: "value1"}, {key: "value2"}, {key: "value3"}]}, {some_key2: [{key: "value4"}, {key: "value5"}, {key: "value6"}]}, {default_val: [{key: "value7"}, {key: "value8"}, {key: "value9"}]}]

const search = makeSearcher (input)

console .log (search ('some_key2'))
console .log (search ())
```

This assumes there is only one object with a given key.  If not, I would look to Nick's solution.

While this is an `O (1)` search function, no logical answer to this is likely to be more than `O (n)`, so I don't really think performance is likely to be a big issue either way.

Answer (score 3):

Same solution as Nick, but with `find` to return object directly:

```js
const data = [
  {
    "some_key1": [
      {"key": "value1"},
      {"key": "value2"},
      {"key": "value3"}
    ]
  },
  {
    "some_key2": [
      {"key": "value4"},
      {"key": "value5"},
      {"key": "value6"}
    ]
  },
  {
    "default_val": [
      {"key": "value7"},
      {"key": "value8"},
      {"key": "value9"}
    ]
  }
];

const getValues = (key = 'default_val') => data.find(o => Object.keys(o)[0] == key);

console.log(getValues('some_key2'));
console.log(getValues());
```

Comment: Not `getValues = (key = 'default_val') =>…`?

Comment: If there can only be one value with a given key this is a better solution than mine.

Comment: @GarrettMotzner Yep, indeed we can do that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`Array.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) with a test that the key of the object is the same as the passed parameter (or `default_val` if one is not passed):

```js
const data = [
  {
    "some_key1": [
      {"key": "value1"},
      {"key": "value2"},
      {"key": "value3"}
    ]
  },
  {
    "some_key2": [
      {"key": "value4"},
      {"key": "value5"},
      {"key": "value6"}
    ]
  },
  {
    "default_val": [
      {"key": "value7"},
      {"key": "value8"},
      {"key": "value9"}
    ]
  }
];

const getValues = (key = 'default_val') => data.filter(o => Object.keys(o)[0] == key);

console.log(getValues('some_key2'));
console.log(getValues());
```

This code will return multiple values if there is more than one value with the same search key. If not, it's more efficient to use [`Array.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) as described in some of the other answers.

Answer (score 1):

This will do:

```
const getValues = (key = "default_val"): InnerObject[] => {
  return data.find(item => item[key])[key];
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more generic solution using [object-scan](https://github.com/blackflux/object-scan)

The main advantage is that it's very easy to target e.g. deeper keys and multiple keys.

```js
// const objectScan = require('object-scan');

const myData = [{ some_key1: [{ key: 'value1' }, { key: 'value2' }, { key: 'value3' }] }, { some_key2: [{ key: 'value4' }, { key: 'value5' }, { key: 'value6' }] }, { default_val: [{ key: 'value7' }, { key: 'value8' }, { key: 'value9' }] }];

const find = (data, key) => objectScan([key], { reverse: false, rtn: 'value' })(data)

console.log(find(myData, '[*].some_key2[*]'));
// => [ { key: 'value4' }, { key: 'value5' }, { key: 'value6' } ]
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="https://bundle.run/object-scan@13.8.0"></script>
```

*Disclaimer*: I'm the author of [object-scan](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-scan)